# Spyder interpreter between Python 2 and 3

Tags: python, anaconda, spyder

I have Conda and Spyder installed for Python 3x, but need to write a script in 2x.
Is it possible to do this without reinstalling Conda for 2x?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you open the Anaconda Launcher app, in the bar at the top there is a drop down menu for environment. Click on this menu, choose new environment, and choose Python 2.x as the Python version. Note that you will have to install a second copy of spyder from inside the Launcher, but you won't have to reinstall the whole stack.

edit: see this to install a new environment without the GUI launcher: http://conda.pydata.org/docs/py2or3.html

2nd edit to clarify comment below: All packages that are installed by default by Anaconda should be available to whichever python environment you set up through Anaconda. To see which packages are available to you, enter

```
help('modules')
```

into your python console.

Comment: Thanks baseq, can I get modules to roll over?

Comment: Typically no, unless the module is compatible with 2.x and 3.x. However, if you already have 2.x modules installed somewhere on your system, you can add those with the PYTHONPATH manager within spyder.